# Custom date format in email body

Tags: 7, datetime, emails

I have a confirmation email. In the confirmation email i print the Date of the event (Date field) in the e-mail body by `[entity-fetched:field_event_date]`.

This is working fine but the Date is printed like `2016-04-13 16:30:00 to 2016-04-13 20:00:00`

How do i print a custom Date format like i.e. `09-Jan-2016` in my email body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Updated] You will need to have the [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) and [Entity Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) modules enabled. Then you'll print custom date format with the following token

```
[entity-fetched:field-event-date:value:custom:d-M-Y]
```

the token should produce the date in the format

```
09-Jan-2016
```

refer to [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for custom date formats.

Comment: I have both above modules enabled. But when i put `[entity-fetched:field_event_date:value:custom:d-M-Y `. Its blank. It doesn't show anything. I also tried  `[entity-fetched:field_event_date:custom:d-M-Y ` What could be the problem?

Comment: try replacing underscores with hyphens

Comment: You're welcome! I updated the answer - please mark it as correct.